# parted rescue - how to discover start\end for deleted partition

Tags: data-recovery

in order to use `rescue` command in `parted` you need the start and end block numbers of the deleted partition. However, if the partition is gone `parted`'s `print` command won't give you those.

How can you discover the start\end block numbers?
Is there a way to go ahead and perform the rescue attempt without them?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend testdisk to discover broken partition table http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk